# Words with Friends summary?

Tags: words-with-friends

In Words With Friends (or any With Friends game), is there anyway I can check the summary of my games - how much did I win/lose? Or compare my standings with another player? It is frustrating when you play quite a number of games and it does not give you a perspective of how well you did.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't believe there is a way to check these stats. These games are *supposed* to be just for fun, but some people do like to know their stats. You could alternativley sign up for a site such as [THIS](http://wwfstats.com/) if you're really serious about your stats.

Comment: They also have facebook 'achievements' that you can reflect upon.  ( but if you play on Facebook, enjoy those ads)

Comment: Thanks for the link. I guess this may be an issue with cross-platform games as they would have to maintain their own leaderboards and stats coz they may not be able to integrate with Game Center.

Answer (score 0):

On Android, recent games win/lost are displayed in the main program screen. However, I do not know how far back this goes. It may be useful only to see how you're doing recently.